# POST (PHP) com JSON

Tags: php, json, post

Bom, eu pesquisei uma resposta e não encontrei então decidi perguntar aqui.
Eu estava fazendo um sistema de Login com JSON e PHP que deveria enviar um POST através do JSON porém a variável "_POST" retorna sempre vazia, prints:

Isso é o JSON que ele envia para o arquivo "login.php".
[image: Isso é o JSON que ele envia.]

E isso é o que retorna (Ps.: eu usei um "echo json_encode($_POST)" no arquivo "login.php" e ele retorna "[]", porém quando o valor é alterado ele também é exibido no "Resposta" do Firebug o que indica que ele está enviando para o link correto.
[image: E isso é o que retorna]
Alguém entende disto?

Comment: Pode postar o código? Ajudaria a entendermos melhor o seu problema.

Comment: Qual linguagem está mandando JSON para o PHP? JavaScript? Se sim, JavaScript puro, jQuery ou outro framework? Poste a parte do seu código que faz o POST (sejá lá em que linguagem for) e a parte do PHP que o recebe. Sem isso jamais poderemos lhe ajudar.

Answer (score 1):

O que pode estar acontecendo é que você está a enviar um POST ou PUT mas sem o 
header de `Content-Type: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"`, isto que indica que é um POST que o server está a receber.

Então para poder pegar o que foi envelopado dentro do cabeçalho HTTP enviado pelo navegador faça o seguinte em PHP:

```
$bodyRequest = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

e depois:

```
$data = json_decode($bodyRequest, true);
```

agora você pode ver o resultado:

```
var_dump($data);
```

Obs.:Eu iria responder em um comentário, mas o stackoverflow não me permite comentar.